# Fault tolerant for Kafka Direct Stream do not work. Checkpoint directory does not exist

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, fault-tolerance, checkpoint, spark-streaming-kafka

I Write app for read data from Kafka topic. And I can’t achieve fault tolerance in the event of a driver failure. The application runs in a k8s cluster using spark submit. When I run my application for the first time, everything goes well, but when I delete pod from the cluster, restarting the application results in an error. `Checkpoint directory does not exist: file:/opt/spark/.../rdd-541`. I use fault-tolerant storage. Below is a piece of code and an error in more detail. Thanks for the help. Let me know if few details.

```
def functionToCreateContext():
    sc = SparkContext("spark-master", "kafka_spark")
    sc.setLogLevel('ERROR')
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)
    kafkaParams = {'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka.cluster'}
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['topic'], kafkaParams)
    statistic_window = kafkaStream.transform(parse_reduce).reduceByKeyAndWindow(lambda x, y: x + y, 
                     lambda x, y: x - y,60, 20)
    top = statistic_window.transform(found)
    top.pprint()
    ssc.checkpoint(cpd)
    return ssc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(cpd, functionToCreateContext)
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

traceback:

```
20/03/10 14:05:19 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from checkpointFile at DStreamCheckpointData.scala:114
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app-spark/kafka_spark.py", line 75, in <module>
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(cpd, functionToCreateContext)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 105, in getOrCreate
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2.tryRecoverFromCheckpoint.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Checkpoint directory does not exist: file:/opt/spark/.../rdd-541
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting this error because your checkpoint directory is not persistent volume. So when you delete the pod, specified directory is also deleted and you are getting that `Checkpoint directory does not exist` error.

The solution would be to use [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to checkpoint directory.

[Here](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/spark-checkpointing/) you can also find an example in exactly same topic.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add, the folder in pod exists but with a different name. for example /opt/spark/.../rdd-205. And streaming context wants to start working with /opt/spark/.../rdd-183 after delete pod. Folder /opt/spark/.../rdd-183 previously existed and disappeared.